# moving multiple rows into a single row column

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table for users where a single user can be up to 20 rows, each row has its own parameter.

The table has five columns and x many rows. Below is a sample extract from the table:

> DOMAIN    OBJECTTYPE  TESTUSERACCOUNT LAST_ACCESS 2023.01.20 08:54:48-0600 > DOMAIN   OBJECTTYPE  TESTUSERACCOUNT LOGIN_STAT  2020.01.14 15:07:38 UTC > DOMAIN    OBJECTTYPE  TESTUSERACCOUNT PASSWORD    2018.05.14 15:17:52
> DOMAIN    OBJECTTYPE  TESTUSERACCOUNT PIN
> DOMAIN    OBJECTTYPE  TESTUSERACCOUNT VM_LAST_LOGIN   2020.01.14 15:07:38 UTC
> DOMAIN    OBJECTTYPE  TESTUSERACCOUNT VM_PIN_UPDATED  2020.01.14 15:07:31 UTC
> DOMAIN    OBJECTTYPE  TESTUSERACCOUNT VOICE#  55555

I have created a query that will return these values by row.

My question can is how turn this into a single row with multiple columns like:

> USER  LAST_ACCESS LOGIN_STAT  PASSWORD    PIN LAST_LOGIN
> PIN_UPDATED   VM_LAST_LOGIN   PHONE TESTUSERACCOUNT   2023.01.20 08:54:48
> -0600 2020.01.14 15:07:38 UTC 2018.05.14 15:17:52     2020.01.14 15:07:38 UTC 2020.01.14 15:07:31
> UTC   55555   USER    LAST_ACCESS LOGIN_STAT  PASSWORD    PIN LAST_LOGIN
> PIN_UPDATED   VM_LAST_LOGIN   PHONE TESTUSERACCOUNT   2023.01.20 08:54:48
> -0600 2020.01.14 15:07:38 UTC 2018.05.14 15:17:52     2020.01.14 15:07:38 UTC 2020.01.14 15:07:31 UTC 55555

I got may result on the internet, but none appear to address my needs?

I would also like to create my own headers in the result.

My query is:

```
SELECT [CLASS], [KEYNAME], [KEY] FROM [DBO].[UserRecords]
    WHERE ([KEYNAME] = 'VOICE#'
    OR [KEYNAME] = 'LAST_ACCESS' 
    OR [KEYNAME] = 'LOGIN_STAT'
    OR [KEYNAME] = 'PASSWORD' 
    OR [KEYNAME] = 'PIN' 
    OR [KEYNAME] = 'S_LOGIN_ACCESS'
    OR [KEYNAME] = 'VM_LAST_LOGIN' 
    OR [KEYNAME] = 'VM_PIN_UPDATE' 
    OR [KEYNAME] = 'WEB_FIRST_LOGIN')
    AND [CLASS] = 'TESTUSERACCOUNT'
```

Where the result is:

> TESTUSERACCOUNT   LAST_ACCESS 2023.01.20 08:54:48 -0600
> TESTUSERACCOUNT   LOGIN_STAT  2020.01.14 15:07:38 UTC
> TESTUSERACCOUNT   PASSWORD    2018.05.14 15:17:52 TESTUSERACCOUNT PIN
> TESTUSERACCOUNT   VM_LAST_LOGIN   2020.01.14 15:07:38 UTC
> TESTUSERACCOUNT   VOICE#  55555

I tried several articles on the internet, but no success. I'm using Microsoft SQL.

SQL database table with user data:
[Database picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubgT6.jpg)

Comment: This is called a PIVOT, have you searched for that?

Answer (score 0):

I brute force SQL query starting with Himanshu's input and leap frogging around in the internet.
My SQL table:
[SQL table header and a record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyj3D.jpg)

My SQL query:

```
   SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT [CLASS] AS USERID, [KEYNAME], [KEY]
    FROM [DBO].[CORREL]
) SRC
PIVOT (
    MAX([KEY]) 
        FOR [KEYNAME] 
        IN (
            [LAST_ACCESS],
            [LOGIN_STAT],
            [PASSWORD],
            [PIN],
            [LAST LOGIN],
            [PIN UPDATE],
            [PHONE#]
        )
    ) AS P
WHERE USERID = 'TESTUSERACCOUNT';
```

Result:
[Result output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTxTd.jpg)